# Prevent spiders from hitting specific webpages and submitting form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, google-search

I have a rails app and a form that it seems like google spiders are filling out.

how do i prevent the spiders from submitting on this specific page?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried robots.txt? What about a captcha?

Robots.txt:
http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to captchas. thanks for the robot.txt link